# Powershell to loop through .CSV to create Distribution List?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I want to modify the below PowerShell cmdlet to create bulk DLs with its members and its aliases.

Using the two cmdlets below:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-distributiongroup?view=exchange-ps

I've managed to create just one DL when executed with the snippets below:

```
$paramNewDistributionGroup = @{
   Name                             = $_.DisplayName
   Alias                            = $_.Alias
   PrimarySmtpAddress               = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
   DisplayName                      = $_.DisplayName
   RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled = $False
   Members                          = $_.Members
}

New-DistributionGroup @paramNewDistributionGroup

$paramSetDistributionGroup = @{
   Identity       = $_.Alias
   EmailAddresses = @{ Add = $_.SecondarySMTPAddress }
}

Set-DistributionGroup @paramSetDistributionGroup
```

How to modify the above script so it takes the .CSV file which looks like the below:

[image]

Using the suggested code from @mklement below, it  throws an error due to the multi-value entries on the below columns:

**SecondarySMTPAddress** column:

> Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on
> parameter 'EmailAddresses'. Cannot convert value
> "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
> to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressCollection". Error: "The
> address  'Execs@domain.com; boss@domain.com ' is invalid: The address
> 'Execs@domain.com; boss@domain.com' isn't a valid Unified Messaging
> address, so a prefix must be specified."

**Members** column:

> Write-ErrorMessage :
> Ex94914C|Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ManagementObjectNotFoundException|Couldn't
> find object " Cella Cat; Maria Aya; Heni Amor; Dio O'meara". Please
> make sure that it was spelled correctly or specify a different object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is on-prem Exchange?

```
$DLs = Import-Csv -Path <filepath>
$DLS | % {
    $paramNewDistributionGroup = @{
       Name                             = $_.DisplayName
       Alias                            = $_.Alias
       PrimarySmtpAddress               = $_.PrimarySmtpAddress
       DisplayName                      = $_.DisplayName
       RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled = $False
       Members                          = $_.Members
    }

    New-DistributionGroup @paramNewDistributionGroup

    $paramSetDistributionGroup = @{
       Identity       = $_.Alias
       EmailAddresses = @{ Add = $_.SecondarySMTPAddress }
    }

    Set-DistributionGroup @paramSetDistributionGroup
}
```

I'm also going to assume the members within your CSV file match one of these AD attributes:

- Name
- Alias
- Distinguished name (DN)
- Canonical DN
- Email address
- GUID

Comment: Hi @John Joseph Trovato, the code throws an error since the content of the .CSV has multiple entries, so how to modify the code to allow accepting or parsing the multiple entries? The error is shown as above.

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer  Are you talking about column C and E?  You can do a split(";").  Let me know that's what you are talking about and I'll send back the code.

Comment: Hi @joseph, yes, the issue was due to the input being multiple string entries.

Comment: @mklenent() Thanks for the comment. That's a good suggestion.  I tend to smoosh all my PS code together.  :)